How can I put all my JS code into a separate file to the HTML?
I been trying to move all JavaScript code into files so that the HTML file doesn't get too cluttered.
This is a small simple example/exercise.
I have been trying to just move the code to a file and src it in, but it doesn't work. Not even when I tried with an onload and init function.
Do I really have to have some code inside script tags in HTML pages or is it somehow possible to move all JS code out to files and src them in?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Guess a number</h1>

  <p>We have selected a random number between 1 and 10. </p>

  <div class="form">
    <label for="guess">Number: </label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" required id="guess" class="guess">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="submit">
  </div>

  <p class="result"></p>

  <script>
    let maxNum = 10;
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
    const guess = document.querySelector('.guess');

    function check() {
      const userGuess = Number(guess.value);

      if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
        result.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
        setGameOver();
      } else {
        if (userGuess < randomNumber)
          result.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
        else
          result.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
      }

      guess.value = '';
      guess.focus();
    }

    submit.addEventListener('click', check);

    function setGameOver() {
      guess.disabled = true;
      submit.disabled = true;
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>



I tried to use onload init function and move the randomizing and some stuff there but it didn't work.

Take all the JS code in that page (note: the JS code, not the <script> tags) and paste it in to a file and name it foo. js. Then change the script tag to <script src="path/to/your-folder/foo.js"></script>. Make sure you leave the script element at the end of the page and you're done. If that doesn't work for you, please edit the question to include the separate HTML and JS file contents.

Note that "it didn't work" is the least helpful piece of text a programmer can get. Of course it didn't work -- you would not have asked otherwise -- tell us what didn't work; how it didn't work. Specifically, what didn't happen that you expected to happen, and/or what happened that you didn't expect to happen? And please [edit] the question to add that information to it.

See: https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/

Your html should look like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Number guessing game</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Guess a number</h1>

  <p>We have selected a random number between 1 and 10. </p>

  <div class="form">
    <label for="guess">Number: </label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="100" required id="guess" class="guess">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit guess" class="submit">
  </div>

  <p class="result"></p>

  <script src="myawesomescript.js"></script>    

</body>

</html>

Then add the following javascript to the new file 'myawesomescript.js' and place it in the same directory as the html:
    let maxNum = 10;
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * maxNum) + 1;
    const result = document.querySelector('.result');
    const submit = document.querySelector('.submit');
    const guess = document.querySelector('.guess');

    function check() {
      const userGuess = Number(guess.value);

      if (userGuess === randomNumber) {
        result.textContent = 'Congratulations! You got it right!';
        setGameOver();
      } else {
        if (userGuess < randomNumber)
          result.textContent = 'Last guess was too low!';
        else
          result.textContent = 'Last guess was too high!';
      }

      guess.value = '';
      guess.focus();
    }

    submit.addEventListener('click', check);

    function setGameOver() {
      guess.disabled = true;
      submit.disabled = true;
    }


It is better to recommend the use of defer attribute than placing the script tag at the end of the body.

You should explicitly close your script tag with </script> rather than having it as a self-closing tag.

I knew that, Andy.
Thanks.
Edited.

@Andy Self-closing tags don't exist in HTML,  there are void elements that do not need a closing tag, but an / in /> is always an error and does nothing. (For embedded context like svg, this is different.)

Note: a closing slash in a void element is not an error; it is allowed but ignored.

I don't understand I can swear I tried this and it didn't work, but now it works, thank you!
